# Android use of static fragments

Tags: android, static, fragment

I have `GridFragment` class, in first screen its implemented with `ViewPager` using `FragmentPagerAdapter`. In second screen I have to display it as just grid. I want to know what should I follow ? I have two options to integrate it in second screen,

1. Call GridFrament class dynamically using FragmentTransaction  or
2. Use it as static fragment by adding fragment tag in xml layout..

Also I have to call some webservices to get the data from server
        which will display in grid. Grid item layout is same. So if I use
        static fragment way, is it safe to call methods directly using dot
        operator on fragment object ? I dont want to use interface just to trigger webservice call.

Answer (score 0):

Try using fragments dynamically using FragmentTransaction and reuse your GridFragment for your multiple implementations. This may be helpful if your application needs to be compatible with different screen sizes and increase flexibility of your application.

Comment: Yes @Rishi, if I consider screen compatibility and future enhancements for the app I will accept your answer. Thanks.